# JQuery PHP AJAX Вынести переменную за пределы своей функции (как вернуть результат из асинхронной функции)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

У нас есть код:

```js
function getLang (string, classes) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../local/get-lang-text.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: ({string: string}),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data){
                var result = data.content;
                $("."+ classes ).text(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

Данный код это функция которая принимает 2 значения и добавляет текст в зависимости от полученного сервером (сервер вернёт текст на нужном языке)

Переменная result работает только в пределах своей функции (если убрать var - тоже)

нужно сделать так что бы функция возвращала сам текст а не выводила его в полученый элемент, то есть нужно сделать так что бы функция принимало одно значение (id нужного текста в массиве переводов) и возвращала переменную result. Суть в том что переменная не хочет выходить за пределы функции ajax

Comment: вопрос не в том, хочет или не хочет, а в том, когда она это делает. вы ищите как переменную вытащить за какие то пределы, а искать надо, как вернуть результат из асинхронной функции.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для решения необходимо сделать функцию асинхронной дописав async перед функцией